# validating a function through a prompt

Tags: javascript

I created a prompt with a function. How do I validate the input with the prompt so that when a number is entered, if there is an error it will alert that the number is incorrect.

```
var value = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number with a decimal in the middle from 0-100" , ""));

var value = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number with a decimal in the middle from 0-100" , ""));

function validNumber(string) {

  let number = parseFloat(string, 10);

  if (number <= 0 || number >= 100) return false;

  if (string !== number.toFixed(2)) return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate the input using a function? Why are you converting the value to an integer?

Comment: @AlonEitan correct.

Comment: You have to call the function and pass it the result of the prompt?

Comment: @AlonEitan It doesn't need to be converted, you can ignore that part.

Comment: Then Ele just posted a great answer

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to convert to `int` before the validation because the function which validates the number is expecting a string.

If the returned value from the validation is `false` then we execute the function `window.alert` to show the error message.

```js
function validNumber(string) {

  let number = Number(string, 10);

  if (number <= 0 || number >= 100) return false;

  if (string !== number.toFixed(2)) return false;

  return true;
}

var value = prompt("Enter a number with a decimal in the middle from 0-100" , "");

if (!validNumber(value)) alert('The entered number is incorrect!');
else console.log(`The entered string is a valid number '${value}'`);
```